# What are those 'x xx' in 'ls -l' command

Tags: 14.04, command-line, locale, ls

When performing `ls -l` I encountered a column I don't recognize.

```
drwxrwxr-x   7 user user    4096 × ×× 29 13:54 .eclipse
drwxrwxr-x   3 user user    4096 × ×× 30 09:30 workspace
drwxrwxr-x   3 user user    4096 ××¦×  1 08:13 something
```

What are those x's?

```
x xx  
xx|x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
LANG=C ls -l
```

There should be a month name, for example (Dec):

```
drwxrwxr-x. 15 user user    4096 Dec  4 16:22 NetBeansProjects
```

May be locale setting are incorrect

Comment: If `LANG=C` has no effect, try `LC_ALL=C` instead.  `LANG` sets a default, which can be overridden by several other things; `LC_ALL` overrides everything else.

Comment: You've explained how to maybe get rid of them, but what *are* they?

Comment: @Octopus The question to ask might be: What language are they?

Comment: @kasperd  they are not in any language.  They are meaningless glyphs that appear when locale char-encoding is inconsistent with the terminal font.  To see what the language related variables are set to,  use the `locale` command.